# Open App Intent of Google Beacon without user tapping Nearby Notification in Android

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, google-beacon-platform, gimbal

I am working on Google Beacon, using Gimbal's Beacon Device. I have setup configuration on gimbal manager and Google's Beacon Dashboard. Activated my Beacon using Gimbal's app. Now, Its working perfectly fine upto some extent.

When any random Android device with BLE support and bluetooth ON arrives in beacon's range, a nearby notification received at user end. When user tap on notification, app intent that I defined on Google Beacon Dashboard opens up my app.

Now, the problem is that I need to trigger the app intent automatically without the need of user tapping on the nearby notification. When user come in beacon's range, if app is installed then open up app's intent otherwise open up playstore to install the app. Right now, this works only when user taps on notification.

Please Help. TIA.

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible.  The notification is designed to get permission from a user before taking action.  Nearby simply will not launch intents without a user tapping a notification.

Comment: Is the same case possible with ibeacons on iOS? Also the nearby notification doesn't generate any sound or vibration when received at user end. Is this also a restriction from Google?

Comment: Notification settings are affected by phone defaults, which google respects.  On iOS, it is the same, yes, you must receive a notification first.

Comment: I have checked my phone's notification settings... It is set to ring and vibrate... Every notification that I receive generates sound + vibration... But when nearby notification is received within beacon's range then there is no sound at all... Completely silent... I have checked the settings of nearby also.... There is nothing there about sound..

Comment: Does our app needs to be at Google Play Store to receive nearby notification at any phone ?

Comment: Yes as far as I remember. To use App intent your app must be published on playstore

Comment: @AhmetCanAkgül are you working on Gimbal's Beacon?

Comment: @FloydKhan thank you. And I am not using Gimbal's Beacon, it s Sensoro.